# Почему .exe файл не видит изменений в используемых .py файлах?

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Компилирую через auto-py-to-exe один скрипт, добавляю в additional files другие .py файлы, из которых происходит импорт определённых переменных. В уже готовой папке с .exe меняю, допустим, в файле settings.py одну переменную, которая будет использоваться в .exe, но там она не меняется, а остаётся такой же, какой была на момент компиляции проекта. Не замечал такого ранее, будто бы всё работало как и должно.

Comment: auto-py-to-exe (pyinstaller) собирает все py файлы в один exe, в том числе и settings.py, а про ваш внешний settings.py готовый exe ничего не знает. Просто используйте какой-нибудь формат конфига для хранения настроек (json, yaml, toml, тысячи их), читайте его тупо через open, вместо импортирования.

Comment: @insolor, а зачем он сохраняет .py файлы, который добавлены, в папку с .exe?

Comment: Без понятия, почему у вас сохраняет. Максимум должно pyc файлы сохранять, не py, если без опции one-file собирается. Возможно вы что-то с настройками намудрили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло только изменение настроек под использование из .json